# Moving a block up a ramp

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

Would this be a valid way to approach this?

> Find the force needed to push a block of mass 5kg to the top of a ramp whose length is 1m and makes a $30^\circ$ angle with the ground.

$$W_{grav} = -mg\Delta y = -5\cdot 10 \cdot \frac 12$$
$$W_{F} = \int F \cdot dr = Fd = F$$

Then $W_{tot} = W_{grav} + W_{F} = \Delta K = \frac 12 m (0)^2 + \frac 12 m(0)^2 = 0$

Thus $-25 + F =0$ and thus $F=25$.

This is just a concept question I found and not HW -- I'm just trying to check that my understanding is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You ask for force needed. This is the force you need against gravity and is mg sin(30) or simply 25N.